# Unable to print output

Tags: java

I've the below Java Program.

```
public class A{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double C = 500.0;
        int init = 0, incr = 0;

        while (init < C) {
            init = incr + 2;

        }
        System.out.println(init);

    }
}
```

Here when i run this program, it is not throwing any errors as well as not showing any errors. Here when i disable the `while` block entirely, then the program runs and prints the value of `init`(0).

Here i have even tried changing `System.out.println(init);` to `System.out.println("Hello");`, but still without disabling the `while` block even this is not printed.

please let me know why this problem occurred, and fault in my code(if so please let me know how to fix it) or any other help.

Thanks,

Rakesh

Comment: it will make your life a lot easier if you try to use debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of init=incr+2;
It should be init=init+2;

because in your program you are just increment inti value to 2 each iteraation ,but if u use init=init+2 it will increment init value upto 499 and then out from while loop.

Comment: public class A{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double C = 500.0;
        int init = 0, incr = 0;

        while (init < C) {
     incr=init;
            init = incr + 2;

        }
        System.out.println(init);

    }
}

Answer (score 6):

```
       init = incr + 2;
```

should be

```
       init = init + 2;
```

Otherwise the loop never terminates, since `incr + 2` is always 2.

Comment: Hi Eran, Thanks for the reply, here can i do something like `init = init + 2;` and in the next line `incr = init`, will this run or the same above error shoots?

Comment: @user3872094 Why do you need two variables? Also, `init += 2` for extra sugar.

Comment: @user3872094 You don't do anything with `incr`. Why would you want to assign the value of `init` to it?

Comment: I need it seperately, `incr` is used for other purposed

Comment: @user3872094 There is no problem with adding `incr = init`, but you could use `init` instead, since both would contain the same value.

Answer (score 1):

change it to init = init +2 . Because everytime you are adding the value of incr and assining to init.

Answer (score 1):

change it to init = init +2 . .